# Is platform.env available when prerendering with sveltekit & adapter-cloudflare?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages

I have a `+page.server.js` file with a `export async function load({ platform }) {}` function. When I set `export const prerender = true` at the top, `platform.env` is undefined. Without prerender it works and I can access my R2 bucket. This is all in production and *not* local.

I tried multiple combinations and configurations. There is no documentation on this issue, neither from cloudflare nor from sveltekit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`platform.env` cannot be pre-rendered, because that is for the env vars on Cloudflare (see the image below) and not your dev environment's env vars (where the pre-rendering happens). To access those, the Svelte compiler would need your Cloudflare credentials. If you need them pre-rendered, add a `+layout.server.js` file to your source tree and store your variables there.

[image]

Comment: This is happening in production during the build. At least, that's what I thought, since I'm using cloudflare pages. And platform.env is supposed to have my R2 bindings. I'm now using fetch to pull files from my R2 bucket, but that's not a nice solution.

Comment: "This is happening in production during the build":

Build and production both run on CF architecture, but run on two entirely different servers: The CI/CD server near you build your artifacts once (so your SK app) and that server deploys it to the CF edge network, so those might *seem* like they're the same server, they are not. You either have to do it like this or disable prerendering :/